# Python's subprocess check_ouput() return code meaning

Tags: python, subprocess

Is there a doc somewhere which indicates what the different return codes of python's subprocess check_output() command means? I'm seeing the returncode equal 3, and I have no idea what is setting that value and/or what it means.

Example code:

```
try:
    output = subprocess.check_output(cmd,
                                     stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
    print e.returncode
```

This code is printing 3.

Comment: `print "e"` seems *very* unlikely to be able to print `3` :-)

Comment: I think you should read the API document before asking here.

Comment: oops, yea sorry I just hacked up the code example and wasn't being very careful. Updated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Python `subprocess.check_output()` doesn't itself return a *code,* it returns the *output* of the command being run. The doco can be found [here](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output).

If you're seeing an error code in that string, it's almost certainly specific to whatever you're trying to run, *not* a result of `subprocess` itself.

If, however, you're capturing the `CalledProcessError` exception caused by a non-zero return code (which can be extracted from the `returncode` attribute), that's *still* specific to whatever you're running.

In both cases, the documentation you need to check is that of whatever tool `subprocess` is running.